# Bind value in dropdown based on change event of another dropdown using Javascript

Tags: html.dropdownlistfor

I have two drop downs .
I want to bind data in a cause of loss based on value selected in type of loss using javascript

My function is below:

```
function ddlTypeOfLoss_change() {
debugger;
var ddlTypeOfLoss = (document.getElementById('<%=ddlTypeOfLoss.ClientID%>').value);
 $('#dvInjury').hide();
 $('#ddlCauseOfLoss').val("0");

if (ddlTypeOfLoss == "A") {

 $('#ddlCauseOfLoss').val("A");
 $('#dvInjury').show();
}
else if (ddlTypeOfLoss == "I") {

$('#ddlCauseOfLoss').val("I");
 }
else if (ddlTypeOfLoss == "O") {
   $('#ddlCauseOfLoss').val("O");
        }
    }
```

My HTML code:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeOfLoss" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" CssClass="form-control  select form-control-round"data-live-search="true" onchange="ddlTypeOfLoss_change()">

<asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="selected">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="A">Accident</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="I">Illnes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="P">Preventive</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="O">Others</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCauseOfLoss" runat="server"
```

CssClass="form-control select form-control-    round"data-live-search="true">

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="selected">-Select</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="A">Accident Injuries</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="O">Others</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="I">Illnes</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```